# Cloud foundry nodejs sample app not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud-foundry, predix

I'm just beginning to use cloud foundry.

I ran [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-sample-app-nodejs) node js sample app of cloud foundry on predix (I just changed the app name in manifest.yml). The code is fine locally and can be pushed to the cloud using cf CLI. The app status in the console is `started` for both of them. But when I go to the URL, the site can't be reached. Please help.

**Edit**

The [microservice template](https://github.com/PredixDev/predix-nodejs-starter) is not running locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cloud, make sure you're using the `https://` protocol.  This is required in Predix cloud.

Locally, what errors do you see?